# Get a pointer to a list element in Emacs Lisp

Tags: lisp, elisp

For example, I have a list:

```
(setq foo '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

Then I need to get a pointer to its 3rd index element (which contains `4` in the example):

```
(setq p (SOME_FUNCTION foo 3))
```

The element with p address can be moved to another list so I can't just save its current `foo`'s index.

And I need to be able to say later on:

```
(push 0 foo)
=> (0 1 2 3 4 5)
(setf p 444)
```

and list `foo` must be `(0 1 2 3 444 5)` afterwards.

Is this possible in Emacs lisp?

Comment: That is't so LISPy. Get a tutorial for LISP and work through it. Emacs LISP (as do many LISPs) has `nth`, so you'd get the 3rd element by `(nth 2 foo)`

Comment: @vonbrand I tried (setq p (nth 3 foo)) (setf p 444) but foo still contains (1 2 3 4 5).

Comment: Aside from the question, for beginners who are wondering why (setf p 444) cannot have any effect on the original list, the reason is that (setq p obj) simply make the variable p refer to the specified target object. (Also true in Python and many other dynamic languages) Also, numbers are immutable (again true in many other dynamic languages as well). This means that numbers are to be considered as objects whose state cannot change. Nevertheless, one can make a variable refer to a different number than before, or even to an object that is not a number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, you can't store the "address" of an object. However, you can refer to a cons cell (a cons cell is what lists are made of). The cons cell could later be modified using `setcar` and `setcdr`.

For example:

```
(defvar my-cons-cell nil)

(defun my-save-cons-cell (cons-cell)
  (setq my-cons-cell cons-cell))

(defun my-set-car-in-saved-cons-cell (value)
  (setcar my-cons-cell value))

;; Test

(setq foo '(1 2 3 4 5))

(my-save-cons-cell (cdr (cdr (cdr foo))))

(push 0 foo)

(my-set-car-in-saved-cons-cell 444)
```

Here, `foo` has the value `(0 1 2 3 444 5)`.

Note that this is really un-lisp like and breaks the functional programming paradigm...

Answer (score 5):

You can do

```
(setq p (nth 3 foo))
```

and it stores in `p` the value stored at the index you want.  You can also do

```
(setf (nth 3 foo) 444)
```

to store 444 at that place.  But if you try to do something like

```
(setq pointer (nth 3 foo))
...
(setf pointer 444)
```

that won't work.  In Emacs's trunk I have recently added `gv-ref` and `gv-deref` which would work just fine in such a case.  They work pretty much like C's `&` and `*`:

```
(setq pointer (gv-ref (nth 3 foo)))
...
(setf (gv-deref pointer) 444)
```

Comment: `(setf (nth foo 3) 444)` gives me "Wrong type argument: integerp, (1 2 3 4 5)"

Comment: Emacs trunk from 2 days ago: `(setq p (gv-ref (nth 3 foo)))` returns `((lambda nil (car c)) lambda (gv--val) (setcar c gv--val))` and `(setf (gv-deref p) 444)` gives "Symbol's value as variable is void: c".

Comment: The error on `(setf (nth foo 3) 444)` is because you swapped `foo` and `3`.  And the problem with `gv-ref` is because it only works in `lexical-binding` mode.